# iterate color array only show one element

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try below code to iterate the color array. Currently it only show one color.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\colours}{{"00FF00","0000FF","4f81bd","c0504d","9bbb59","8064a2","4bacc6","f79646","0000ff"}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \name [count=\i] in \colours {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\colour}{\colours[\i-1]}
  \definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{\colour}
  \fill[mycolor] (\i,0) --++ (1,0) --++ (0,1) --++ (-1,0) --cycle;
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want is show all colors defined in the array.

#Update with pgfplots

If put the same into a pgfplots, I saw only the last cycle has been draw on graph:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\colours}{{"4f81bd","c0504d","9bbb59","8064a2","4bacc6","f79646","0000ff"}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\num{dim(\colours)}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 6cm,
        height = 4cm,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        xmin=0,xmax=8,
        ymin=0,ymax=1,
        enlarge x limits=.1
    ]
   \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\num}{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\i}{int(#1)}
      \typeout{ \i }
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\colour}{\colours[\i-1]}
      \definecolor{mycolor\i}{HTML}{\colour}
      \fill[mycolor\i] (axis cs:\i,0) -- (axis cs:{\i+1},0) -- (axis cs:{\i+1},1) -- (axis cs:\i,1) -- cycle;
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That's more weird:
[image]

Comment: It would be simpler, if you removed one pair of braces and the quotation marks. The problem is that with two pairs of braces, you essentially have only one element in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pgffor` only sees one element in your list: `{...}`.

If you switch to a syntax without the `{}` around the list, pgffor can see the individual elements:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\colours}{00FF00,0000FF,4f81bd,c0504d,9bbb59,8064a2,4bacc6,f79646,0000ff}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \name [count=\i] in \colours {
  \definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{\name}
  \fill[mycolor] (\i,0) rectangle ++(1,1);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you would like to keep your syntax, you could wrap another loop around it, which will "unpack" the first layer of `{...}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\colours}{{"00FF00","0000FF","4f81bd","c0504d","9bbb59","8064a2","4bacc6","f79646","0000ff"}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \macro in \colours {
\foreach \name [count=\i] in \macro {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\colour}{\colours[\i-1]}
  \definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{\colour}
  \fill[mycolor] (\i,0) --++ (1,0) --++ (0,1) --++ (-1,0) --cycle;
}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: good answer, one weird thing is when I try to repalce the \name with \colours[\i-1], it only show one color again! ` \definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{\colours[\i-1]}`

Comment: @lucky1928 If you want use the `\colours[\i-1]` syntax, you should better use @PaulGaborit's answer

Comment: Thanks, more weird thing is if use the same in pgfplots, only the last cycle draw, I have updated into my question.

Comment: @lucky1928 maybe ask a new question to get eyes of some pgfplots experts on this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep your array, you can use the `dim` function:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\colours}{{"00FF00","0000FF","4f81bd","c0504d","9bbb59","8064a2","4bacc6","f79646","0000ff"}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\nbcolours{dim(\colours)}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\nbcolours} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\colour}{\colours[\i-1]}
    \definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{\colour}
    \fill[mycolor] (\i,0) --++ (1,0) --++ (0,1) --++ (-1,0) --cycle;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, does that means the array define actually is 2 dim? 1xn, but how \colours[\i-1] can access the elements?

Comment: @lucky1928 The array is only one dimension. The PGF mathematical engine (See pgf manual, part "Mathematical and Object-Oriented Engines" or section "Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: Operators") defines the `[]` operators to access array.